# 3sum leetcode problem using 2sum

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge

> Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such
>   that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives
>   the sum of zero.
>
> Note: The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

`a + b + c = 0`

Solution is to just convert this into two pointer technique of solving 2SUM problem. Traverse the array and for each element check if rest of the array has 2 elements that sum up to `-a`.

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        def two_pointer(nums, target):
            '''two pointer technique and it is caller responsibility to pass proper nums'''
            first = 0
            second = len(nums) - 1
            two_sums = []
            while first < second:
                two_sum = nums[first] + nums[second]
                if two_sum < target:
                    first += 1
                elif two_sum > target:
                    second -= 1
                else:
                    two_sums.append([nums[first]] + [nums[second]])
                    while first+1 < len(nums) and nums[first] == nums[first+1]:
                        first += 1
                    while second-1 >= 0 and nums[second] == nums[second-1]:
                        second -= 1
                    first += 1
                    second -= 1
            return two_sums
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        nums = sorted(nums)
        three_sums = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(nums)-2:
            two_sums = two_pointer(nums[i+1:], -nums[i])
            for j in range(len(two_sums)):
                three_sums.append([nums[i]] + two_sums[j])
            while i+1 < len(nums) and nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
                i += 1
            i += 1
        return three_sums
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Algorithm

I find one problem here, you create `len(nums)-2`  times copy of array by calling `nums[i+1:]`. It's fast but not necessary. In general helps [islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) iterator to avoid copies of sub-arrays.

### Iterators

Lines `index_of_list_element += constant` in loop strongly suggest rewrite code to use proper iterators to get more *python way* code. In your code `i, first, second` are indexes for unique numbers in `nums`. `two_pointer()` function also can be iterator to avoid create temporary list inside main loop.

### Code

Idea of code with iterators

```
def three_sum(nums):
    def uniques(nums_sorted, start, stop, step):
        prev = None
        for idx in range(start, stop, step):  # xrange() in python2
            value = nums_sorted[idx]
            if value != prev:
                prev = value
                yield idx, value

    def two_pointer(nums_sorted, neg_a, start):
        biter = uniques(nums_sorted, start, len(nums_sorted), 1)
        citer = uniques(nums_sorted, len(nums_sorted) - 1, start, -1)
        (bidx, b), (cidx, c) = next(biter), next(citer)
        while bidx < cidx:
            two_sum = b + c
            if two_sum == neg_a:
                yield b, c
            if two_sum <= neg_a:
                bidx, b = next(biter)
            if two_sum >= neg_a:
                cidx, c = next(citer)

    nums = sorted(nums)
    return [[a, b, c] for aidx, a in uniques(nums, 0, len(nums) - 2, 1)
                      for b, c in two_pointer(nums, -a, aidx + 1)]
```